# Laravel block direct access to ajax route

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

How to Laravel block/redirect direct access to ajax route?

I created Middleware OnlyAjax.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OnlyAjax
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ( ! $request->ajax())
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add in Karnel.php

```
'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\OnlyAjax::class,
```

My Route

```
Route::middleware(['ajax'])->group(function () {
            Route::group(['middleware' => ['roles'], 'roles' => [1, 2, 3, 4]], function () {
                Route::post('select-plan', 'AjaxController@selectPlan')->name('ajaxSelect.plan');
            });
        });
```

But I got error

`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

`No message`

When I change `Route::post` to `Route::get` it's working. But I want to use `Route::post`

Comment: Try using `$request->wantsJson()`

Comment: `$request->wantsJson()` Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the 2 method defined and on the controller decide what to do with the traffic.

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'select-plan', 'AjaxController@selectPlan')->name('ajaxSelect.plan');
```

and in the controller.

```
if (Request::isMethod('get')){
    // redirect user
}

if (Request::isMethod('post')){
    // do logic for post method
}
```